# Modeling human relationships

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy, data-modeling

I'm looking for the best way to define relationships between two people and query it in SQLAlchemy. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. Here is what I have so far but I don't know if I should be using a model as link table like this. Advice?

Example `character_a` = `student` `character_b` = `teacher`

or `[[relationship.character_b, relationship.character_b.role] for relationship in character.relationships]` to get a list of related characters and their roles.

```
class Character(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'characters'
    story_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('stories.id'))
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    gender = db.Column(db.String(6))
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
    relationships = db.relationship('Relationship', backref='character', lazy='dynamic')

class Relationship(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'relationships'
    character_a_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('characters.id'))
    character_b_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey('characters.id'))
    character_a_role = db.Column(db.String(25))
    character_b_role = db.Column(db.String(25))
```

Answer (score 0):

Database schemas are hard to get right the first time. I suggest you follow the advice of Peter Norvig - write the test cases in english, model them in code (play with the relationships assuming they exist in the database), you will discover the shortcomings of the current design that way. Then you can refine the relationships and when you are done, your code must be as readable as the use cases you wrote in english.